# UIBarButtonItem created using initWithCustomView doesn't trigger action

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibarbuttonitem

I'm updating some old code, and to make more room in a toolbar, I'm converting the Buttons from test to images.  An example of the new and old code in loadView is this:

```
// New code, doesn't work.
UIButton *toggleKeyboardBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
toggleKeyboardBtn.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, showKeyboardImage.size.width, showKeyboardImage.size.height );
[toggleKeyboardBtn setImage:showKeyboardImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
UIBarButtonItem *toggleKeyboardItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toggleKeyboardBtn];
[toggleKeyboardItem setTarget:self];
[toggleKeyboardItem setAction:@selector(toggleKeyboard:)];

// Original code, works jut fine.
UIBarButtonItem *setupItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Setup" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate action:@selector(showSetupView:)] autorelease];
```

My new code is copied from [Cannot set action on UIBarButtonItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8373656/cannot-set-action-on-uibarbuttonitem), and I'm fairly certain that I'm not making their mistake since my text button is working just fine.

showSetupView() is in my AppController.m file, and the setup screen appears and disappears as the button is pressed.

toggleKeyboard(), OTOH, is in the same file as the loadView() routine, and currently consists of this code:

```
//- (void)toggleKeyboard {
- (IBAction)toggleKeyboard:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Entering toggleKeyboard()...");
    hiddenKeyboard = !hiddenKeyboard;
    [self prepareToolbarsAndStatusbar];
}
```

Needless to say, although I see the button-press animation, I never see the NSLog message.  And one last observation, made by accident.  Changing the setAction selector to this:

```
[toggleKeyboardItem setAction:@selector(noSuchRoutine:)];
```

compiles cleanly, possibly indicating that my routine name is being ignored for some reason.

Anyone have any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the answer!  In [button action not responding iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360548/button-action-not-responding-iphone), it's said that the action and target need to be set on the `UIButton`, not the `UIBarButtonItem`.  I don't know if that's new with the latest version of Xcode, but I guess it is since other questions (such as the one I mention above) use a different technique.  Here's my new code:

```
UIButton *toggleKeyboardButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
toggleKeyboardButton.bounds = CGRectMake( 0, 0, keyboardAddImage.size.width, keyboardAddImage.size.height );
[toggleKeyboardButton setImage:keyboardAddImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[toggleKeyboardButton addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleKeyboard) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *toggleKeyboardItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:toggleKeyboardButton];
//[toggleKeyboardItem setTarget:self];
//[toggleKeyboardItem setAction:@selector(toggleKeyboard:)];
```

Comment: good answer! Really solve the problem. This is putting a button inside another.

Comment: Yes!! so simple, it's perfect!

Comment: From the docs : "The bar button item created by this method does not call the action method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user interactions and provide an appropriate response." . `UIBarButtonItem` is not a `UIView` descendant.

Answer (score 1):

Though its too late, but for future references, I would like to quote [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibarbuttonitem/1617151-initwithcustomview?language=objc) for the method,

```
- (instancetype)initWithCustomView:(UIView *)customView;
```

> The bar button item created by this method does not call
>   the action method of its target in response to user interactions.
>   Instead, the bar button item expects the specified custom view to
>   handle any user interactions and provide an appropriate response.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

`-(void)toggleKeyboard`

and

`[toggleKeyboardItem setAction:@selector(toggleKeyboard)];` without `:`

and it made any difference? Is the method declared in the interface file?

Comment: I've started off with that, and jet verified that it still doesn't work.  Thanks, though.  So, what does the colon mean, anyway?

Comment: When you have a method `-(void)myMethod;` , you call it via `[self myMethod]` or via selectors '@selector(myMethod)'. If you have any argument (of any type), then we have `-(void)myMethod:(id)myParameter;`, and when calling, you do `[self myMethod:parameterToSend]` or via selectors '@selector(myMethod:)', and in this case, the UIBarButtonItem takes care of sending the "sender". As you are doing this via code, I guess you don't really need the sender. It should work, maybe you can show more code. And try to put it in viewDidLoad and not in loadView.