# Set action for custom UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've created a `UIView` that has to be added to `BarButtonItem`. I can't set action to this button though. Here's the code I am using:

```
 self.menuBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:self.containerView];
    [self.menuBarButton setTarget:self];
    [self.menuBarButton setAction:@selector(menuButtonTapped)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.menuBarButton;
```

The action doesn't run with success. I also tried to set an action directly to bar button after it's set to custom.

```
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setTarget:self];
        [self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem setAction:@selector(menuButtonTapped)];
```

When I do it for the usual barbutton item it works. Could you help spotting what's wrong?

Comment: Try this:
UIButton* infoButton = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeInfoLight];

[infoButton addTarget:self action:@selector(displayAboutUs)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];

UIBarButtonItem* itemAboutUs =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:infoButton];

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `UIBarButtonItem` initialized with a custom view [expects the view to handle user interaction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithCustomView:):

> The bar button item created by this method does not call the action method of its target in response to user interactions. Instead, the bar button item expects the specified custom view to handle any user interactions and provide an appropriate response.

If your `UIView` doesn't handle any user interaction yet, then as Miken says, you can replace the `UIView` with a `UIButton` that you've configured with `addTarget:selector`.

In particular, if you're trying to set an image, `UIButton` can do that via [`setImage:forState:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIButton/setImage:forState:).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11605923/25637).

Answer (score 0):

When you use a custom view for a UIBarButtonItem, then you have to handle the actions yourself. Replace your custom view with a UIButton, or add a UIButton to your custom view, and then add a target & selector to the button.

Here's an example but keep in mind I'm free-forming this example, so it may not be 100% accurate code but the concept will be the same.

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIBarButtonTypeCustom];
UIBarButtonItem *bbi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
[button addTarget:self selector:@selector(myBtnClk)];
```

Answer (score 0):

To add action to a button you need two things: create a method, then add it to the button. Here is the method (pay attention to the syntax) :

```
- (IBAction) my_method : (id) sender {
UIButton * btn = sender;
}
```

Now the action assignment (where the button was created) :

```
[ my_button addTarget : self
               action : @selector( my_method : )
     forControlEvents : UIControlEventTouchUpInside ];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `- setAction` alone, I recommend using: `- addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`. In iOS (AppKit) there are many type of events. You can take a look at the attached image for reference. Typically Touch up inside is appropriate for button press down.

Comment: Where do I have to call - addTarget:action:forControlEvents: ? I haven't fount this method for self.menuBarButton or self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem

Comment: I too did't find that action for UIBarButtonItem on Ctrl Dragging into my code. It looks like there's only 'action' event for UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

I decided this problem. All answers was about adding target and action to UIButton and then create a UIBarButtonItem with this button. But as I said it's really necessary to set UIView to this button(I've forgotten to say it's necessary because this UIView has animation, maybe that's why all answers was good but wrong for my situation.)
But one answer(https://stackoverflow.com/a/28054357/4464891) from Jason Owen gives me great idea. I have to use my custom view, so I've set selector to my custom UIView by adding UITapGestureRecognizer with `initWithTarget:action:`:

`UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(menuButtonTapped)];
[self.containerView addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];`

And when I click button tapRecognizer runs my selector. So that's it. Hope it'll be helpful for someone=)